# Upgrading from using Gulp to Webpack with Laravel Mix

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

I have been in the process of upgrading a project originally built in Laravel 5.2 to Laravel 5.6.

Back in Laravel 5.2, we were using Gulp with Laravel Elixir. In Laravel 5.6, they are now using Webpack with Laravel Mix.

I found a [gist](https://gist.github.com/rap2hpoutre/e53728c96f551c42a352f1484bbf4934) that seemed to cover most of the steps.

The app was originally built by an agency and then handed on to me when I was hired. In their customised version of the `app.js` file, they have this:

```
// Bootstrap Rim
System.import('rim/bootstrap.js').then(function(Rim) {
    Rim.Bootstrap.all();
});
```

Which is part of the greater `app.js` file:

```
System.config({
    baseURL: '/js'
});

require('./core/bootstrap');
require('./core/components');

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
window.App = new Vue({
    el: '#page',

    /**
     * Bootstrap the application. Load the initial data.
     */
    mounted: function() {
        // Bootstrap Rim
        System.import('rim/bootstrap.js').then(function(Rim) {
            Rim.Bootstrap.all();
        });

        let self = this;
    },

    methods: {
        navigate: function(location) {
            window.location = location;
        }
    }
});
```

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36103641/dynamic-system-import-with-webpack?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) for using `System.import()` in Webpack and used the top [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41497903/1739852):

1. I installed the [System dynamic import package](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/syntax-dynamic-import/) as mentioned; `npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import`
2. I added a `.babelrc` file to the root of my project with the below contents (Laravel Mix automatically picks this up when running Webpack)

   {
     "plugins": ["syntax-dynamic-import"]
   }

When I run `npm run dev` though, I get the below error:

> ERROR  Failed to compile with 44 errors
>   8:29:23 AM These dependencies were not found:
>
> - rim/bootstrap.js in ./resources/assets/js/app.js
> - rim/dialog.js in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib?{"cacheDirectory":true,"presets":[["env",{"modules":false,"targets":{"browsers":[">
>     2%"],"uglify":true}}]],"plugins":["transform-object-rest-spread",["transform-runtime",{"polyfill":false,"helpers":false}],"syntax-dynamic-import"]}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./resources/assets/js/components/admin/fermentables-screen.vue,
>     ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib?{"cacheDirectory":true,"presets":[["env",{"modules":false,"targets":{"browsers":[">
>     2%"],"uglify":true}}]],"plugins":["transform-object-rest-spread",["transform-runtime",{"polyfill":false,"helpers":false}],"syntax-dynamic-import"]}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./resources/assets/js/components/admin/hops-screen.vue and 8 others
> - rim/form-notification.js in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib?{"cacheDirectory":true,"presets":[["env",{"modules":false,"targets":{"browsers":[">
>     2%"],"uglify":true}}]],"plugins":["transform-object-rest-spread",["transform-runtime",{"polyfill":false,"helpers":false}],"syntax-dynamic-import"]}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./resources/assets/js/components/admin/adjuncts-screen.vue,
>     ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib?{"cacheDirectory":true,"presets":[["env",{"modules":false,"targets":{"browsers":[">
>     2%"],"uglify":true}}]],"plugins":["transform-object-rest-spread",["transform-runtime",{"polyfill":false,"helpers":false}],"syntax-dynamic-import"]}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./resources/assets/js/components/admin/notifications-screen.vue
>     and 7 others
> - rim/message.js in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib?{"cacheDirectory":true,"presets":[["env",{"modules":false,"targets":{"browsers":[">
>     2%"],"uglify":true}}]],"plugins":["transform-object-rest-spread",["transform-runtime",{"polyfill":false,"helpers":false}],"syntax-dynamic-import"]}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./resources/assets/js/components/admin/yeasts-screen.vue,
>     ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib?{"cacheDirectory":true,"presets":[["env",{"modules":false,"targets":{"browsers":[">
>     2%"],"uglify":true}}]],"plugins":["transform-object-rest-spread",["transform-runtime",{"polyfill":false,"helpers":false}],"syntax-dynamic-import"]}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./resources/assets/js/components/admin/hops-screen.vue and 14 others
> - rim/select2.js in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib?{"cacheDirectory":true,"presets":[["env",{"modules":false,"targets":{"browsers":[">
>     2%"],"uglify":true}}]],"plugins":["transform-object-rest-spread",["transform-runtime",{"polyfill":false,"helpers":false}],"syntax-dynamic-import"]}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./resources/assets/js/components/common/components/select2-component.vue,
>     ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib?{"cacheDirectory":true,"presets":[["env",{"modules":false,"targets":{"browsers":[">
>     2%"],"uglify":true}}]],"plugins":["transform-object-rest-spread",["transform-runtime",{"polyfill":false,"helpers":false}],"syntax-dynamic-import"]}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./resources/assets/js/components/common/components/select2-ajax-component.vue
>
> To install them, you can run: npm install --save rim/bootstrap.js
>   rim/dialog.js rim/form-notification.js rim/message.js rim/select2.js
>
> These relative modules were not found:
>
> - ../../images/search/delete_icon.png in ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??postcss!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-4!./resources/assets/less/app.less
> - ../../images/search/search_icon.png in ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??postcss!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-4!./resources/assets/less/app.less
> - ../img/checkbox_icons.png in ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??postcss!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-4!./resources/assets/less/app.less
> - ./select2-spinner.gif in ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??postcss!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-4!./resources/assets/less/app.less
> - ./select2.png in ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??postcss!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-4!./resources/assets/less/app.less
> - ./select2x2.png in ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??postcss!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-4!./resources/assets/less/app.less
>     fs.js:1001   binding.stat(pathModule._makeLong(path), statValues);

This all worked fine when I was using Gulp, so I'm sure it can't be that hard to get this working...

Running `npm install --save rim/bootstrap.js rim/dialog.js rim/form-notification.js rim/message.js rim/select2.js` resulted in a bunch of errors trying to fetch the files externally.

The `app.js` is in `resources/assets/js/app.js` and the `rim/bootstrap.js` is part of a compiled `rim.js` file located in `public/js/rim.js`.

A sample of what that `rim.js` file is included below:

[image: rim.js file]

**What more do I need to get this working?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switching from Gulp to Webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39753642/switching-from-gulp-to-webpack)

Comment: @MikeStratton similar, but not a duplicate. It seems my issues stem from System.import() which that question does not shed any light to.

Comment: Upgrading from Gulp to Webpack is a likely to be a multi-faceted problem that is not addressed by fixing just your System.import() problem.

Comment: @MikeStratton quite possibly. The current issue I’m dealing with is this though; when and if I can get past it then I’ll see if there are any other issues. Otherwise I will just stick with Gulp.

Comment: I would suggest sticking with Gulp, if possible.